# doctrine2 one-to-many not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, symfony-2.1, many-to-one

This is a simple problem, but after going through all similar threads in Stackoverflow and elsewhere without success, the problem remains.

I can't get bidirectional One-To-Many relationship working. Biomass.field is accessible (owning side), but Field.biomasses (inverse side) is not.

---

Tables (removed expendable fields)

```
CREATE TABLE `field` (
  `field_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`field_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `biomass` (
  `biomass_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`biomass_id`),
  KEY `FK_field_has_0m_biomasses_idx` (`field_id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `biomass`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_field_has_0m_biomasses` FOREIGN KEY (`field_id`) REFERENCES 
`field` (`field_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

---

Field.php

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Acme\MainBundle\Entity\Field
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="field")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Field {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->biomasses = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @var string $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="field_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /*
     * var ArrayCollection $biomasses
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Biomass", mappedBy="field", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $biomasses;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get biomasses
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getBiomasses() {
        return $this->biomasses;
    }

    /**
     * Set biomasses
     *
     * @param ArrayCollection $biomasses
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function setBiomasses(ArrayCollection $biomasses) {
        $this->biomasses = $biomasses;
        return $this->biomasses;
    }

    /**
     * Add Biomass
     *
     * @param Biomass $biomass
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function addBiomass(Biomass $biomass) {
        $biomass->setField($this);
        return $this->biomasses[] = $biomass;
    }

    /**
     * Set biomass
     *
     * @param Biomass $biomass
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function removeBiomass(Biomass $biomass) {
        return $this->biomasses->removeElement($biomass);
    }       

    function __toString() {
        return $this->getId();
    }
}
```

---

Biomass.php

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Acme\MainBundle\Entity\Biomass
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="biomass")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Biomass {
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="biomass_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Field
     *
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Field", inversedBy="biomasses")
     * @JoinColumn(name="field_id", referencedColumnName="field_id")
     */
    private $field;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }    

    /**
     * Set field
     *
     * @param Field $field
     * @return Biomass
     */
    public function setField(Field $field = null) {
        //$field->addBiomass($this);
        $this->field = $field;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get field
     *
     * @return Field
     */
    public function getField() {
        return $this->field;
    }

    function __toString() {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

---

FieldController.php

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entities = $em->getRepository("AcmeMainBundle:Field")->findAll();

foreach($entities as $field) {
    foreach($field->getBiomasses() as $biomass) {
        print_r($biomass->getId());
    }
}
```

This results with :Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:[...]\MainBundle\Controller\FieldController.php line 39

ArrayCollecion is not being created, because Doctrine does not call constructors, it uses a serialize/unserialize trick to instantiate classes.

I have dummy data in those tables and the data is accessible, so it seems that doctrine is not creating biomasses object at all.

---

Environment
Symfony-2.1.2, Apache/2.4.3 (Win64), PHP/5.4.6-Win64, MySQL Community Server 5.5.28

EDIT: fixed Biomass.field referencing column name typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BioMass.php the @JoinColumn should point to **field_id** not **id** in the BioMass table.

```
 /**
 * @var Field
 *
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Field", inversedBy="biomasses")
 * @JoinColumn(name="field_id", referencedColumnName="field_id")
 */
```

Comment: You are right: However i had already tried that and also renaming PK columns to 'id'. The problem doesn't seem to be in entity code, but rather doctrine proxy or cache issue. I'm digging meanwhile.

Comment: If you call `$field->setBiomasses(new \ArrayCollection())`, you don't get the error `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:[...]\MainBundle\Controller\FieldController.php line 39` correct?